# String: Minimum bounds for maximum height

Tags: xcode, swift, nsstring, cgsize

I want to calculate the minimum bounds for a rectangle needed to fit a string (multi line) with a specific font.

It should look something like this:

```
FROM:

 ----------------------------------
|Sent when the application is about|
|to move from active to inactive   |
|state.                            |
 ----------------------------------

TO:

 -------------------------
|Sent when the application|
|is about to move from    |
|active to inactive state.|
 -------------------------
```

As you can see, the height stays the same, the width changes to the minimum value necessary.

Initially I though I could use `boundingRectWithSize` (constraint to maximum width) to first get the minimum height needed and then call `boundingRectWithSize` (constraint to calculated height) the get the width. But this produces wrong results when calculating the width in the second step. It does not consider the max height but simple calculates the width for a single line string.

After that I found a way to get the proper result but executing this code takes really long which makes it of no use to me:

First calculate the needed rect for constraint width:

```
var objectFrame = Class.sizeOfString(string, font: objectFont, width: Double(width), height: DBL_MAX)
```

then the width:

```
objectFrame.size.width = Class.minWidthForHeight(string, font: objectFont, objectFrame.size.height)
```

using:

```
class func minWidthForHeight(string: NSString, font: UIFont, height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    let deltaWidth: CGFloat = 5.0
    let neededHeight: CGFloat = rect.size.height
    var testingWidth: CGFloat = rect.size.width

    var done = false
    while (done == false)
    {
        testingWidth -= deltaWidth

        var newSize = Class.sizeOfString(string, font: font, width: Double(testingWidth), height: DBL_MAX)

        if (newSize.height > neededHeight)
        {
            testingWidth += deltaWidth
            done = true
        }
    }
    return testingWidth
}

class func sizeOfString(string: NSString, font: UIFont, width: Double, height: Double) -> CGRect
{
    return string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: height),
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font],
        context: nil)
}
```

It gradually calculates the height for a given width (- 5.0 pixels each new step) and checks wether the height stays the same. As soon as the height changes, it returns the width of the previous step.
So now we have a bounding rectangle where the string for a certain font fits perfectly without any wasted space.

But as I said, this takes a really long time to calculate, especially when doing it for many different strings simultaneously.

Is there a better and faster way to do this?

Comment: I do not know a solution on how to calculate this with one step, but maybe you could replace your linear search for the best width with a binary search. Take two values, with the smaller one being too narrow and the larger one sufficiently wide. Check for the width half way in between these values. If it is still good, set the larger value to the tested width, if it is too small, adjust the smaller value. Repeat. It is not O(1) but O(log n) instead of O(n). Depending on how many tries you have to make for each string, this could already speed things up.

Comment: Of course this requires quite clever (not perfect) guesses for the initial values, especially the smaller one, which is supposed to be too small. The longer the text, the bigger this number can be chosen, I think. Maybe the smaller number can be set to `(1 - 1/numberOfLinesWithMaxWidth) * maxWidth` initially.

Comment: This works pretty well. It still takes quite a long time to calculate but that time has significantly been reduced.

Comment: Do you want me to post that as an answer? Although james_alvarez answer is (at least to some extent) similar to my comments. But I can still post it, if you'd like me to do so.

Comment: If you could wait a little, that would be great. I'm still perfecting the method and I would lime to update my post as soon as I have something that works well. I would then post my code and that might help somebody in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this code below is my final approach to to question at hand. It's pretty fast and works well for me. Thanks to @Nero for getting me on the right track.

```
class func minFrameWidthForHeight(string: NSString, font: UIFont, rect: CGRect) -> CGFloat
{
    if (string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()).count <= 1)
    {
        return rect.size.width
    }

    var minValue: CGFloat = rect.size.width / 2
    var maxValue: CGFloat = rect.size.width

    var testingWidth: CGFloat = rect.size.width
    var lastTestingWidth: CGFloat = testingWidth
    let neededHeight: CGFloat = rect.size.height

    var newSize = rect

    while (newSize.height <= neededHeight)
    {
        lastTestingWidth = testingWidth

        testingWidth = (maxValue + minValue) / 2

        newSize = CalculationHelper.sizeOfString(string, font: font, width: Double(testingWidth), height: DBL_MAX)

        if (newSize.height <= neededHeight)
        {
            maxValue = testingWidth
        }
        else
        {
            minValue = testingWidth
        }
    }

    return lastTestingWidth
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem, as users will not have the calculation helper class.

Comment: Also, the algorithm below will definitely be faster, as well as more accurate

Comment: Please look at my original post, there is the class you are referring to. It is simply a `boundingRectWithSize` call. I will be testing your code soon as well. Until then, I just wanted to share my approach.

Comment: Plus this algorithm will never work, it will always return the original width.  This is because newSize.height and neededHeight are both initially set by rect

Comment: You are after something like the lower part of my algorithm, but you are still some of the way off... I can edit my answer to include your calculation helper class if you like?

Comment: If you like, that would be great!

Comment: Incidentally even if you sorted out the problems with this code, you would half the time have word wrapping just leave a single word at the bottom etc...

Comment: Its not the right answer for me because your method exports wrong values and takes almost 3 to 4 times longer to calculate. Nero paved the path to the correct answer.

Comment: It works perfectly well - and anyone who reads the code you have posted will see that yours will just return the original width. Oh well enjoy your points.